# How can I limit my API requests per second to the Google Analytics API?

Tags: google-analytics, polymer, google-analytics-api

I have created a dashboard application with the Google Analytics API. The dashboard features 10 different charts.

```
<google-analytics-view-selector></google-analytics-view-selector>
<google-analytics-date-selector
startDate="30daysAgo"
endDate="yesterday">
</google-analytics-date-selector>

<div class="row">
<div class="six columns">
      <google-analytics-chart
        type="area"
        metrics="ga:totalEvents"
        dimensions="ga:date"
        filters="ga:eventCategory=@publication">
        <h3 class="bold">Total Publication Openings</h3>
      </google-analytics-chart>      
</div>

<div class="six columns">
       <google-analytics-chart
          type="area"
          metrics="ga:totalEvents"
          dimensions="ga:date"
          filters="ga:eventCategory=@download">
          <h3 class="bold">Downloads</h3>
        </google-analytics-chart>
</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
<div class="six columns">
      <google-analytics-chart 
        type="pie" 
        metrics="ga:sessions" 
        dimensions="ga:deviceCategory" 
        sort="-ga:sessions" 
        max-results="6"> 
        <h3 class="bold">Device Category</h3>
      </google-analytics-chart>     
</div>
<div class="six columns">
      <google-analytics-chart
        type="column"
        metrics="ga:totalEvents"
        dimensions="ga:date"
        filters="ga:eventCategory=@publication"
        segment="gaid::RqaosWyGRFevGjBRNK_WYw">
        <h3 class="bold">iOS Openings</h3>
      </google-analytics-chart>
</div>
</div>


<div class="row">
<div class="six columns">
      <google-analytics-chart
        type="column"
        metrics="ga:totalEvents"
        dimensions="ga:dayOfWeekName"
        sort="-ga:totalEvents"
        filters="ga:eventCategory=@publication">
        <h3 class="bold">Openings Per Weekday</h3>
      </google-analytics-chart>    
</div>
<div class="six columns">
      <google-analytics-chart
        type="column"
        metrics="ga:totalEvents"
        dimensions="ga:eventLabel"
        sort="-ga:totalEvents"
        max-results="5"
        filters="ga:eventCategory=@article;ga:eventLabel!@Untitled">
        <h3 class="bold">Popular Articles</h3>
      </google-analytics-chart>
</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
<div class="six columns">
        <google-analytics-chart
        type="column"
        metrics="ga:totalEvents"
        dimensions="ga:date"
        filters="ga:eventCategory=@publication"
        segment="gaid::GOz2kMV2QzGv1YwHNLybqw">
        <h3 class="bold">Desktop Openings</h3>
      </google-analytics-chart>
</div>
<div class="six columns">
      <google-analytics-chart
        type="area"
        metrics="ga:totalEvents"
        dimensions="ga:hour"
        filters="ga:eventCategory=@publication">
        <h3 class="bold">Total Openings Per Hour</h3>
      </google-analytics-chart>
</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
<div class="six columns">
       <google-analytics-chart
        type="column"
        metrics="ga:totalEvents"
        dimensions="ga:eventLabel"
        filters="ga:eventCategory=@search"
        sort="-ga:totalEvents"
        max-results="5">
        <h3 class="bold">Popular Searches</h3>
      </google-analytics-chart>
</div>
<div class="six columns">
       <google-analytics-chart
        type="bar"
        metrics="ga:totalEvents"
        max-results="5"
        dimensions="ga:eventAction"
        filters="ga:eventCategory=@download;ga:eventAction!@Unknown"
        sort="-ga:totalEvents">
        <h3 class="bold">Publication access</h3>
      </google-analytics-chart>
</div>
</div>
```

It works perfectly fine but throws an error response every time. The error code is a 403, which is exceeding the daily quotas. However, I have checked the developers console and the daily usage is not exceeded. Google also states a limit of 1 query per second, which I think is the one violated because the entire dashboard is loaded at the same time.

Can I make the individual charts load after one another or how can I circumvent this issue?

Comment: [Limits and quotas docs](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/limits-quotas): If you log into the developer console you can raise the 1 query per second per user to a maximum of 10 qps per user, and even add the parameter `quotaUser` to go beyond that. But what you are not going to be able to get around is the 10 concurrent requests per view. While your code is very clean it is not very efficient, If you queried the API directly (w/o polymer) you could get most of your data required with one or two queries and then format the results how you see fit.